# stackoverflow com problema de mencionar pessoas?

Tags: suporte

Quando eu for comentar, eu tento adicionar `@` para mencionar o nome do usuário de stackoverflow. As vezes mostra o nome e as vezes não mostra. Isso é o problema do meu navegador ou problema stackoverflow ? Isso acontece de vocês ?

Comment: Provavelmente é algum engano no entendimento de como funciona o sistema de @. Se puder por mais detalhes de uma situação concreta em que o problema se manifeste, talvez dê pra ajudar melhor.

Comment: Quando usas `@` para referir a mesma pessoa que colocou a pergunta ou resposta onde comentas isso acontece. É esse o caso?

Comment: @Sergio, isso mesmo. É normal ?

Comment: Possivel duplicata ou relacionado [Como funcionam as menções e notificações com @usuario?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/943/3635)

Comment: Essa aqui por exemplo não consigo mencionar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174961/como-redimensionar-imagem-independente-do-tamanho

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente você está tentando marcar o próprio autor da pergunta. o stackoverflow não permite que o autor da pergunta seja marcado com @, pois o mesmo sempre será notificado de qualquer atualização.